# How can I read an input string of unknown length?

Tags: c, scanf

If I don't know how long the word is, I cannot write `char m[6];`,
The length of the word is maybe ten or twenty long.
How can I use `scanf` to get input from the keyboard?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char  m[6];
    printf("please input a string with length=5\n");
    scanf("%s",&m);
    printf("this is the string: %s\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

please input a string with length=5
input: hello
this is the string: hello

Comment: use pointer realloc combination

Comment: You can drop the `&` in `scanf("%s",&m)` since `m` is already a pointer to the first element of `m[]` in this expression.

Comment: You should use `"%5s"` to ensure no buffer overflow.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**Enter while securing an area dynamically**

E.G.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *inputString(FILE* fp, size_t size){
//The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(*str)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(*str)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(*str)*len);
}

int main(void){
    char *m;

    printf("input string : ");
    m = inputString(stdin, 10);
    printf("%s\n", m);

    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof(char)`? Ugh.

Comment: @Jens Pfff, that will probably be optimised away. No problems. But if you were to do a global find-and-replace of `char` with `wchar_t`, this solution would still work, unlike other solutions, that would need more tinkering!

Comment: @Jens I like to write in this way as is defined as `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: @MrLister It isn't assumed `size` specified for the first is 0 because there is nonsense. And though we can check it.

Comment: If at all, you should multiply by `sizeof (*str)`. But still, it's rampant paranoia and a code smell.

Comment: @MrLister Which is why the proper way, if at all, is to multiply with `sizeof (*str)` so you don't even have to *edit* the multiplication when the type changes.

Comment: It's definitely the case that `str[len]='\0'; return realloc(str, len);` will result in the terminator being discarded.  I think you meant `str[len++] = '\0'`.

Comment: @MrLister i had been misunderstood. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: Also, the same error with `if (len>size)`.  And `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: OK, now this (and any `malloc()`-based solution) faces the problem of what to do when we run out of memory.  `main()` needs some error handling for when `inputString()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @sh1 `main() needs some error handling for when inputString() returns NULL.` I leave it to him(her).

Comment: (size *= 2) is better.

Comment: it depends on the characteristics of the data handled by the optimization.

Comment: why is `size_t size = 10` ?

Comment: @jaska An expected value which is roughly of the required initial value but may be any value.

Comment: It is possible to avoid such a cost if the processing within the size that is expected since because costly as such is carried out in realloc.

Comment: Isn't `realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);` the same as `malloc(sizeof(char) * size)`? What is the reason that `realloc` is preferred here?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Just means the unification of the format. There is no problem with `malloc(sizeof(char) * size)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no, `realloc` can't be replaced by `malloc`. If you changed it you would have to `free` the memory before.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `malloc` creates memory. If you created new memory and didn't free the old you'd have a memory leak. `realloc` takes care of that while `malloc` doesn't.

Comment: @germanfr It does not have an associated.  I say about `realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size); the same as malloc(sizeof(char) * size)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no, it's not the same. Replacing the first with just the second would lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what memory chunk? I am talking about what you said. You said replacing `realloc(...)` with `malloc(...)` leads to the same behavior, while this is false. When you `realloc` successfully, it frees the previous memory, while `malloc` doesn't. So they are not interchangeable as you said.

Comment: @germanfr No. I said about `realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size); the same as malloc(sizeof(char) * size)`. I don't say  the same of `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ok I get you. I didn't notice the NULL there :)

Comment: @germanfr What do you say pointing to anything to do with __old__ ( "the old you'd have a memory leak")?

Comment: It was a waste of time.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY nothing. I didn't notice the NULL so I thought you where talking about replacing every `realloc` with `malloc`, not just the first. I'm sorry.

Comment: is the last `realloc` in `inputString` really necessary ?

Comment: @artm No. It just makes the size of the buffer equal to the size of the input string (plus one for the null character).

Comment: Can you explain why `inputString()` doesn't just return `str`? Is this to free the unused bytes if the length string input from stdin is less than size (initial size)?

Comment: @MinhTran Yup, It is intended to no include unused areas.

Comment: @MrLister I do love me some wide wchar_tacters using `wwchar_t_t`! I use them all the time in my battery wchar_tger to display an error message if the battery is too far diswchar_tged or has an unwchar_tacteristic wchar_tging curve. (Damaged batteries are dangerous to rechar_tge and may cost a surwchar_tge to recycle)

Comment: @immibis You forgot to press Alt+W to search for whole words only.

Comment: It may leak memory if the `realloc` fails in `return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);`. That call is a waste of time anyway since I doubt any system has finer malloc granularith than 16 bytes

Comment: @BLUEPIXY There is memory leak in the code, you are assigning value to a unallocated memory cell at `str[len++]=ch;` Your code will try to assign a value to 11th Cell(index 10) even though you originally allocated memory only for 10 characters at the start.

Answer (score 26):

With the computers of today, you can get away with allocating very large strings (hundreds of thousands of characters) while hardly making a dent in the computer's RAM usage. So I wouldn't worry too much.

However, in the old days, when memory was at a premium, the common practice was to read strings in chunks. `fgets` reads up to a maximum number of chars from the input, but leaves the rest of the input buffer intact, so you can read the rest from it however you like.

in this example, I read in chunks of 200 chars, but you can use whatever chunk size you want of course.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readinput()
{
#define CHUNK 200
   char* input = NULL;
   char tempbuf[CHUNK];
   size_t inputlen = 0, templen = 0;
   do {
       fgets(tempbuf, CHUNK, stdin);
       templen = strlen(tempbuf);
       input = realloc(input, inputlen+templen+1);
       strcpy(input+inputlen, tempbuf);
       inputlen += templen;
    } while (templen==CHUNK-1 && tempbuf[CHUNK-2]!='\n');
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    char* result = readinput();
    printf("And the result is [%s]\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is a simplified example with no error checking; in real life you will have to make sure the input is OK by verifying the return value of `fgets`.

Also note that at the end if the readinput routine, no bytes are wasted; the string has the exact memory size it needs to have.

Comment: Needs error handling for `realloc()` returning `NULL` (and, consequently, for `readinput()` returning `NULL`).

Comment: Need to check the return value of `fgets()`, else code may enter infinite loop.

Comment: @chux OK, added a note about that.

Comment: I think there's an issue with this on the first realloc (realloc when input is NULL). This could point to arbitrary memory, and thus the strcat may not have the intended result (i.e. input should be just the contents of the buffer). Instead, rather than trying to store a string of length templen which has been allocated, it tries to store a string of strlen(arbitrary data) + templen, and gives a "malloc() memory corruption" error.

Comment: @BrendanHart Aw, nobody saw that in six years. Fixed by doing a strcpy rather than a strcat.

Comment: To lose the line feed add [`tempbuf[strcspn(tempbuf, "\n")] = 0;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221) after `fgets` line.

Answer (score 17):

I've seen only one *simple* way of reading an arbitrarily long string, but I've never used it.  I think it goes like this:

```
char *m = NULL;
printf("please input a string\n");
scanf("%ms",&m);
if (m == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "That string was too long!\n");
else
{
    printf("this is the string %s\n",m);
    /* ... any other use of m */
    free(m);
}
```

The `m` between `%` and `s` tells `scanf()` to measure the string and allocate memory for it and copy the string into that, and to store the address of that allocated memory in the corresponding argument.  Once you're done with it you have to `free()` it.

This isn't supported on every implementation of `scanf()`, though.

As others have pointed out, the easiest solution is to set a limit on the length of the input.  If you still want to use `scanf()` then you can do so this way:

```
char m[100];
scanf("%99s",&m);
```

Note that the size of `m[]` must be at least one byte larger than the number between `%` and `s`.

If the string entered is longer than 99, then the remaining characters will wait to be read by another call or by the rest of the format string passed to `scanf()`.

Generally `scanf()` is not recommended for handling user input.  It's best applied to basic structured text files that were created by another application.  Even then, you must be aware that the input might not be formatted as you expect, as somebody might have interfered with it to try to break your program.

Comment: Note that `"%ms"` is not standard C --- it's probably either a POSIX extension or a GNU extension.

Comment: @TimČas: It's part of Posix 2008, which is a standard. There was an earlier similar GNU extension and a similar BSD extension; the Posix standard is intended to unify the various implementations. It's quite possible that it will find its way into a future C standard.

Answer (score 11):

There is a new function in C standard for getting a line without specifying its size. `getline` function allocates string with required size automatically so there is no need to guess about string's size. The following code demonstrate usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        /* handle error */
    }

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not in the C standard, but it does exist in POSIX, so it's quite widely available

Answer (score 6):

If I may suggest a safer approach:

Declare a  buffer big enough to hold the string:

`char user_input[255];`

Get the user input in a **safe** way:

`fgets(user_input, 255, stdin);`

A safe way to get the input, the first argument being a pointer to a buffer where the input will be stored, the second the maximum input the function should read and the third is a pointer to the standard input - i.e. where the user input comes from.

Safety in particular comes from the second argument limiting how much will be read which prevents buffer overruns. Also, `fgets` takes care of null-terminating the processed string.

More info on that function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

EDIT: If you need to do any formatting (e.g. convert a string to a number), you can use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi) once you have the input.

Comment: but the OP asking he doesn't know how much he is gonna input what if he randomly wants to input with > 255

Comment: IMO `fgets(user_input, sizeof user_input, stdin);` is safer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Until you use a pointer instead of an array ;)

Comment: but let say you write a shell. Do you really want to limit to 255 or any fixed value ? First answer seem better at handling string of unknown at compile time sized-string.

Answer (score 4):

Safer and faster (doubling capacity) version:

```
char *readline(char *prompt) {
  size_t size = 80;
  char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
  int c;
  size_t len = 0;
  printf("%s", prompt);
  while (EOF != (c = getchar()) && c != '\r' && c != '\n') {
    str[len++] = c;
    if (len == size) str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (size *= 2));
  }
  str[len++]='\0';
  return realloc(str, sizeof(char) * len);
}
```

Comment: Usually the prompt is provided by the programmer. So you can not say it is unsafe. It can be unsafe if the programmer specifies some format specifier in the prompt. But I changed it.

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is redundant; `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: `prompt` should be a `const char *`.

Comment: You should check all `malloc` and `realloc` calls for errors.

Comment: The unchecked multiplication `size *= 2` can overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Take a character pointer to store required string.If you have some idea about possible size of string then use function

```c
char *fgets (char *str, int size, FILE* file);
```

else you can allocate memory on runtime too using `malloc()` function which dynamically provides requested memory.

Answer (score 1):

Read directly into allocated space with `fgets()`.

Special care is need to distinguish a successful read, end-of-file, input error and out-of memory.  Proper memory management needed on EOF.

This method retains a line's `'\n'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FGETS_ALLOC_N 128

char* fgets_alloc(FILE *istream) {
  char* buf = NULL;
  size_t size = 0;
  size_t used = 0;
  do {
    size += FGETS_ALLOC_N;
    char *buf_new = realloc(buf, size);
    if (buf_new == NULL) {
      // Out-of-memory
      free(buf);
      return NULL;
    }
    buf = buf_new;
    if (fgets(&buf[used], (int) (size - used), istream) == NULL) {
      // feof or ferror
      if (used == 0 || ferror(istream)) {
        free(buf);
        buf = NULL;
      }
      return buf;
    }
    size_t length = strlen(&buf[used]);
    if (length + 1 != size - used) break;
    used += length;
  } while (buf[used - 1] != '\n');
  return buf;
}
```

Sample usage

```
int main(void) {
  FILE *istream = stdin;
  char *s;
  while ((s = fgets_alloc(istream)) != NULL) {
    printf("'%s'", s);
    free(s);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  if (ferror(istream)) {
    puts("Input error");
  } else if (feof(istream)) {
    puts("End of file");
  } else {
    puts("Out of memory");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that I have arrived after 4 years and am too late but I think I have another way that someone can use. I had used `getchar()` Function like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//I had putten the main Function Bellow this function.
//d for asking string,f is pointer to the string pointer
void GetStr(char *d,char **f)
{
    printf("%s",d);

    for(int i =0;1;i++)
    {    
        if(i)//I.e if i!=0
            *f = (char*)realloc((*f),i+1);
        else
            *f = (char*)malloc(i+1);
        (*f)[i]=getchar();
        if((*f)[i] == '\n')
        {
            (*f)[i]= '\0';
            break;
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{
    char *s =NULL;
    GetStr("Enter the String:- ",&s);
    printf("Your String:- %s \nAnd It's length:- %lu\n",s,(strlen(s)));
    free(s);
}
```

here is the sample run for this program:-

```
Enter the String:- I am Using Linux Mint XFCE 18.2 , eclispe CDT and GCC7.2 compiler!!
Your String:- I am Using Linux Mint XFCE 18.2 , eclispe CDT and GCC7.2 compiler!! 
And It's length:- 67
```

Answer (score 0):

i also have a solution with standard inputs and outputs

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
    char *str,ch;
    int size=10,len=0;
    str=realloc(NULL,sizeof(char)*size);
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=scanf("%c",&ch) && ch!="\n")
    {
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size)
        {
            str = realloc(str,sizeof(char)*(size+=10));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",str);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: return value of `scanf` should be compared for the number of elements you read, not `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using standard libraries of C and also creating a string type (alias of char*) like in C++

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* string;

typedef struct stringClass {
    char ch;
    struct stringClass *next;
}stringClass;

int get_str(char **str) {
    char ch, *buffer, a;
    stringClass *new = NULL;
    stringClass *head = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    int c = 0, k = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        new = malloc(sizeof(stringClass));
        if(new == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        new->ch = ch;
        new->next = NULL;
        new->next = head;
        head = new;
    }

    tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        c++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if(c == 0) {
        *str = "";
    } else {
        buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (c + 1));
        *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (c + 1));
        if(buffer == NULL || *str == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            buffer[k] = tmp->ch;
            k++;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        buffer[k] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0, j = strlen(buffer)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            a = buffer[i];
            buffer[i] = buffer[j];
            buffer[j] = a;
        }
        strcpy(*str, buffer);
        // Dealloc
        free(buffer);
        while (head != NULL) {
            tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    string str;

    printf("Enter text: ");
    get_str(&str);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```