# C - Reading string of unknown length clarification

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

Question related to this:
[How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-a-an-input-string-of-unknown-length)

Several questions:

What does the line `if(!str)return str` mean?

Why is `int ch` an integer? Isn't it supposed to be a char?

What is the purpose of the `size` given to the function exactly?

Asking in a separate question because I understood the method, just not some of the stuff under the hood.

Comment: `if(!str)` is checking if the allocation failed.

Comment: @H2CO3 We are not going to pollute the question queue with little questions.  It is far more efficient and produces higher quality, when small highly related questions are grouped together into one *Question*.

Comment: @randomusername Ugh, we're splitting hair here, aren't we? That's cute. Then let's do it in an even better way: what if I told you that this question(tuple) shouldn't have been asked at all? All the explanation of these basic constructs can be found in a decent beginners' tutorial; Stack Overflow is not a "teach me the language by explaining basic programs" site.

Comment: @H2CO3 The OP had a question, they sought out help and thus they should be able to get it. Sure, SO may not be the right place to ask this, so tell us where on the Stack Exchange network we should move this question to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `if (!str) return str;` basically means `if (str == NULL) return NULL;` which is just error checking the return value of `realloc`.

The reason we make `ch` an `int` is because the function `fgetc` returns an `int` (that is how we can have `EOF` be returned yet `EOF` isn't a legal `char` value).

The `size` argument simply represents the initial size of the buffer that we allocate.  So if the person calling the function has a pretty good (not necessarily exact) idea of how big the string will be, they can give it in this parameter and save a lot of time by avoiding extra calls to `realloc`.

Comment: Mucho gracias random. Cleared up some things beyond the questions asked here as well.