# Dynamically read user input strings in C

Tags: c

Given a user input of unknown length (consisting of words with maximum length 100). Is there a way to read it dynamically string by string?

It is my understanding that scanf reads a string until a space is reached, so I tried using scanf but it enters an infinite loop.

```
char buf[101];
while (scanf("%s", buf))
{
    //something is done with the string
}
```

Comment: `while (scanf("%100[^\n]%*c", buf)) { ... }`  NO `';'` following the closing `)`

Comment: @David C. Rankin `scanf("%100[^\n]%*c"` reads nothing if first character is `'\n'`.

Comment: Have you tried `while (scanf("%100s", buf) == 1)` to reads the _words_, one at a time?

Comment: Yes, you can add a space before the `%` if you want to insure against a `'\n'` to begin with. (Oh, nevermind, I thought he was having trouble reading words with spaces, not wanting to *tokenize* the line....)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870485/608639)

Answer (score 8):

> Given a user input of unknown length (consisting of words with maximum length 100) is there a way to read it dynamically string by string?

Building your own function, instead of `scanf` would help to achieve this

- Here, I've created a function `scan` which would dynamically take in the string by increasing it's size over each iteration
- I've use the additional header files `string.h` and `stdlib.h` for the following reasons :

  1. functions in [**stdlib.h**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdlib_h.htm) *(click to know more)* library file are **useful for dynamic allocation** of memory.
  2. functions in [**string.h**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm) *(click to know more)* library file are **useful to handle strings**.

> **Note:** the input from the user stops when he enters the string `end`.

```
#include <stdio.h>  //the standard library file
#include <stdlib.h> //library file useful for dynamic allocation of memory
#include <string.h> //library file with functions useful to handle strings

//the function    
char* scan(char *string)
{
    int c; //as getchar() returns `int`
    string = malloc(sizeof(char)); //allocating memory

    string[0]='\0';

    for(int i=0; i<100 && (c=getchar())!='\n' && c != EOF ; i++)
    {
        string = realloc(string, (i+2)*sizeof(char)); //reallocating memory
        string[i] = (char) c; //type casting `int` to `char`
        string[i+1] = '\0'; //inserting null character at the end
    }

    return string;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *buf; //pointer to hold base address of string

    while( strcmp((buf=scan(buf)),"end") ) //this loop will continue till you enter `end`
    {
        //do something with the string

        free(buf); //don't forget to free the buf at the end of each iteration
    }

    free(buf); //freeing `buf` for last input i.e, `end` 

}
```

---

> let's just `//do something with the string` to see whether the above code works or not :)

I change the following while loop in main function :

```
    while( strcmp((buf=scan(buf)),"end") )
    {
        //do something with the string
    }
```

to

```
while( strcmp((buf=scan(buf)),"end") )
{
    printf("you entered : %s\n",buf);
    printf("size        : %u\n",strlen(buf));
    printf("reversing   : %s\n",strrev(buf));

    printf("\n-------------------\n");

    free(buf);
}
```

and now,

**input :**

```
hall
of
fame
stay in it
end
```

**output :**

```
you entered : hall
size        : 4
reversing   : llah

-------------------
you entered : of
size        : 2
reversing   : fo

-------------------
you entered : fame
size        : 4
reversing   : emaf

-------------------
you entered : stay in it
size        : 10
reversing   : ti ni yats

-------------------
```

---

Comment: Not a real concern for OP, but consider `i<100 && (c=getchar())!='\n'` instead of `(c=getchar())!='\n' && i<100`.  If there is no room, why read and throw away a character?  Better to read it next time.

Comment: `EOF` indicates an input error or end-of-file occurred (no more input).  The read loop should have 3 ending conditions: `i<100 && (c=getchar())!='\n' && c != EOF`.  Else on end-of-file, code will continually read 100 `EOF`.  This also implies  `strcmp((buf=scan(buf)),"end")` is a problem.  What happens if `"end"` does not exist?  How does the calling code distinguish between a line of only `"\n"` and end-of-file?  Good luck +1.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!

```
while (scanf("%s%c", buf, &c))
    {
        //do something with the string
        if (c == '\n') break;
    }
```

Comment: What happens when `scanf("%s%c", buf, &c)` returns 1 or `EOF`?  Is `if (c == '\n')` safe to execute?

Comment: Unclear why code stops at `'\n'` as the post said "Given a user input of unknown length", there maybe be many lines of input.

Comment: `Is there a way to read it dynamically string by string?` but your solution to your question is not dynamical.. @lezlemon

Comment: @CherubimAnand maybe I didn't make myself clear, it reads strings until it reaches '\n' which is what I wanted. The maximum length of the individual strings is known, but their number is not.

Comment: @chux I should have been more clear. The input will always be strings (words) separated by a space, until it reaches '\n', so c will be equal to ' ' until the end of the line is reached, which is the end of the input, for my purposes.

Comment: Information like that buried in one of the answers does not change the post.  That new information belongs there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
while (scanf("%s", code) == 1)
{
    // no need for second scanf call
    // do whatever you like here
}
```

Edit: Try this.

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
//Above line makes program to take input from file.
//File should be present in same folder
char c[50];
while(scanf("%s",c)!=EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n",c);
}
```

Comment: I tried both == 1 and > 0, it still enters an infinite loop..

Comment: That's because you are leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin` and since `scanf` with `%s` reads up to the next `'\n'` (well, you know the rest of the story -- now)

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: It gets to end of the input and then waits for input again. I don't know what condition to use to make it break the loop.

Comment: Ok. All these methods work when input is given from a file, they wont work for manual input.

Comment: Added line to take input from file in answer

Comment: @David C. Rankin  Repeated calls to `scanf("%s",c)` does **not** leave an `'\n'` in `stdin`.  White-space is first consumed.

Comment: `scanf("%s",c)` is as safe as `gets(c)`.  Both should not be used.