# Input value to struct from scanf

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf

I am trying to learn struct in C. The code complies fine, when I try to input a value, it crashes. I tried with an `int` member and it works.

```
typedef struct node{
    char *productName;
    int price;
    struct node *next;

}node;

int main (){
    node *head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter a product name: ");
    scanf("%s", &head->productName);
    printf("Product entered:%s",head->productName);
    //scanf("%d", &head->price); // this works
    //printf("Price entered:%d",head->price);

}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: 1. Do not cast malloc - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). 2. What is `prodeuctName` pointing to?

Comment: productName doesn't have memory allocated to keep whatever you are getting in scanf().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, `%s` with `scanf()` expects a `char *` argument, what you're passing is a `char **`.

That said, even after correcting that (*removing the `&`*), `head->productName` is uninitialized and it does not point to a valid memory location. Accessing uninitilized memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make the pointer point to a *valid* memory before you can read from or write into it.

Finally, you should always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Combining all of them, something like

```
node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
if (head) {
    head->productName = malloc(32); //some arbitary size
    if (head->productName) {
        printf("Enter a product name: ");
        scanf("%31s", head->productName);
        printf("Product entered:%s",head->productName);
    }
}
```

should do the job.

---

Note: A generic advice, don't forget to `free()` the returned pointer by memory allocator functions to avoid any possible memory leak, as your code grows bigger.

Comment: last but not the least. don't forget to free the memory you have allocated

Comment: @bansi Well, this particular case won't make any difference, still, a valid point. :)

Comment: Writing everything in 'if' isn't a good style of writing, it's better to just test and fail in 'if'. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, You need to write it something like this:

```
/*Following code is not tested - Just a sample*/
typedef struct node{
    char *productName;
    int price;
    struct node *next;
}node;

int main (){
    node *head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if( head == NULL ) 
     /*fail*/
    printf( "Size of product name:");
    scanf( "%d",&size);
    head->productName = malloc(size);
    if( head->productName == NULL ) {
       /*fail*/
    }
    printf("Enter a product name: ");
    scanf("%s", head->productName);
    printf("Product entered:%s",head->productName);
    /*scanf("%d", &head->price); // this works
      printf("Price entered:%d",head->price);*/

    /*Do stuff with node here*/
    free(head->productName);
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if( head->productName == NULL ) {
       /*fail*/
    }.... scanf("%s", head->productName);`.. whole `if` thing is useless then. Assuming you're trying to write a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scanf("%ms", &head->productName);
```

see
[how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length)

may be this what you are looking for.