# What syntax am i missing out on regarding char arrays and pointers to them

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax, char

I was doing some testing for a program of mine and was wondering why the program was crashing when entering my function. Don't mind the logic of the program, since i was still in the phase of making sure i understood how to use my tools at hand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Constants */
#define HEX_CAPITAL_LETTERS_BEGIN 65
#define HEX_CAPITAL_LETTERS_END 90
#define HEX_NUMBERS_BEGIN 48
#define HEX_NUMBERS_END 57
#define EXIT_SUCCES 0

/* Prototypes */
void codeToField(char *charArray, int i, int hexFloor, int hexCeil, char *outputArray);

/* Main Function */
int main(void) {
  char *code, warehouse, product, qualifiers;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter a MMOC product code: ");
  scanf("%s", &code);

  codeToField(code, i, HEX_CAPITAL_LETTERS_BEGIN, HEX_CAPITAL_LETTERS_END, &warehouse);
  codeToField(code, i , HEX_NUMBERS_BEGIN, HEX_NUMBERS_END, &product);

  strcpy(&qualifiers, code + i);

  printf("\n\nWarehouse: %s\nProduct: %s\nQualifiers: %s\n", &warehouse, &product, &qualifiers);

  return EXIT_SUCCES;
}

void codeToField(char *charArray, int i, int hexFloor, int hexCeil, char *outputArray) {
  int j = 0;
  while (charArray[i] >= hexFloor && charArray[i] <= hexCeil) {
    outputArray[j] = charArray[i];
    i++;
    j++;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use numbers like `65` and `90` instead of `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'0'`, etc.?

Comment: Why are you trying to `strcpy` into a single character?

Comment: @M.M as I said, don't mind anything but the problem at hand. Was still trying to find out what i wanted and really just tested things out. Everything put the problem was commented out before posting haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  char *code, warehouse, product, qualifiers;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter a MMOC product code: ");
  scanf("%s", &code);
```

Here, `code` is an uninitialized pointer to memory so once you do the `scanf` call, your program is hosed.

I think you want something more like

```
char code[100];
printf ("Enter a MMOC product code: ");
scanf ("%s", code);
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the maximum array size? :)

Comment: Yes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length.  Or just use C++ and strings.

Comment: @MikeLundAndersen you can also use malloc to put your array on the heap instead of the stack..

Comment: @vicatcu yeah but then you still need a maximum size

Answer (score 1):

First, this does not do what you want:

```
char *code, warehouse, product, qualifiers;
```

The only pointer is `code`, the other are just a single `char`. You're printing them as strings with `printf`, and you use `warehouse` and `product` as `outputArray` in your function. They need to be pointers (or arrays) too:

```
char *code, *warehouse, *product, *qualifiers;
```

Then you need memory. The pointers are still uninitialized, so any reading from them is undefined behavior.

You can either allocate memory with automatic storage duration (on the stack) or dynamically (on the heap).

Stack:

```
char codestr[100];
code = codestr;
```

but then, you could also just have declared `code` as

```
char code[100];
```

to avoid to have two variables.

If you want to allocate the memory dynamically, you would use `malloc`:

```
code = malloc(100);
```

Don't forget to free the memory again:

```
free(code);
```

`warehouse`, `product`, `qualifiers` all need memory too. Some of the array sizes could be deduced form the defined constants.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `code` has no memory allocated to it. It is an uninitialized pointer. Try this instead:

```
// ...
char myString[16], *code, warehouse, product, qualifiers;
code = &myString[0];
int i = 0;

printf("Enter a MMOC product code: ");
scanf("%15s", code);
// ...
```

Comment: You should use a length limiter in the scanf format string to avoid buffer overflows