# c: reading const char* into a variable in sscanf?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to scan a string/*char into a variable and pass it into a function, but I get the error "`format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'const char *'`". I need `*info` to be a const char, but if I change that, I get other errors.

How would I scan in the `const char *info` correctly into `sscanf()`?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    blk *block;
    char *line;
    const char *info;

    block = block_new();

    printf("insert info");

    while ( (line = readline()) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%s", info);
        insert(block, info);
        free(line);   
    }     
}
```

insert: `insert(blk *block, const char *info)`

When I change to `char *info` instead of `const char`, I get the error:

```
warning: variable 'info' is uninitialized when used here
sscanf(line, "%s", info);

note: initialize the variable 'info' to silence this warning
    char *info; = NULL
```

Comment: Apart from removing the `const` qualifier to satisfy the compiler, `line` and `info` are both *uninitialised variables*. They don't point to anything specific. So `sscanf(line, "%s", info);` will not be able to do anything sensible, it is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: *Why* do you "need `*info` to be a const char"?

Comment: "*I need `*info` to be a const char*" - no, you need it to be a suitably-long **array** of  **non-`const`** char, or a pointer to a suitably-large,  dynamically-allocated, **non-`const`** space.  Whether dynamically allocated or not, the contents of the space cannot be `const` because you need to modify them (via `sscanf`).

Comment: @WeatherVane `*info` should be a const char because the function insert() needs a const char parameter

Comment: After the question edit, `info` still needs to point to allocated memory. When `sscanf` derefences the `NULL` pointer it will crash.

Comment: It is acceptable to supply a non-const argument to a `const` parameter, but not the other way round.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay! How should I allocate memory without knowing how big `info` is?

Comment: The question is getting too broad - this is not a tutorial service! You could use a fixed length array longer than any input you expect, such as `char info[1000];` and restrict the input with `sscanf(line, "%999s", info);` or you could follow up the many similar questions on SO such as [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length)

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your code and with what you want.

A `const char* string;` declares a pointer to `char`. You can change the location of
where your pointer is pointing, you cannot change the contents of the memory
pointed to by the pointer.

```
const char *string = "Hello";
char line[] = "a b c";

string = "World"; // legal
string[0] = 'w';  // illegal

string = line;    // legal
string[0] = 'A';  // illegal
```

So using a `const char*` for reading input with `scanf` & Co is pointless.

> When I change to `char *info` instead of `const char`, I get the error:

Did you mean change from `char *info` to `const char`? That is even worse,
`info` could hold **one character only**.

Please don't ignore the compiler warnings and don't silence them. The compiler
is telling

> warning: variable 'info' is uninitialized when used here

---

You also are doing

```
const char *info;
...
sscanf(line, "%s", info);
```

Let's forget about the `const` for a moment, let's pretend it's not there.
`info` is an uninitialzed pointer, that means it points to nowhere in
particular. Passing it to `sscanf` yields undefined behaviour, because `sscanf`
is trying to write into a memory location where you may or may not have access
to.

How to fix it:

```
char info[100];
...
sscanf(line, "%s", info);
```

`info` is now an array of `char` that can hold strings with maximal length of 99
characters.

Note that having a `const` pointer where you want to save input from the user,
makes no sense, it cannot be constant by design, because the user input **will**
modify it.

It is perfectly fine to do the other way round: to use a `const char*` for a
non-cost `char*`, useful when you need to call a function that takes a `const char*` for an argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const char *txt)
{
    if(txt == NULL)
        return;

    printf("The text passed is: \"%s\"\n", txt);
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[] = "Hello world";
    foo(line);
    return 0;
}
```