# how do i fill between the brackets of my array, can i use strlen?

Tags: c

need string lenght for my scanf , how do i determine what number to put betwen [], can use A[strlen].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char A[];
    printf("enter a string");
    scanf("%s", A);
    printf("%s", A);
    getch();

}
```

Comment: You can’t. That’s the fun of handling open-ended user input. What happens if someone pastes three gigabytes worth of text into their terminal-emulator?

Comment: No. If you want to have an *exact* length for `A`, then you first need *another* array in which *any* length of text can be entered, so you can measure it.

Comment: why you didn't try to use `char *A`?

Comment: @Jin: because that leads to a compiler warning ("use of an uninitialized variable"), and ignoring that will lead to a seg fault. Or, possibly worse: it *may* run. Or it may not.

Comment: so should i just insert a random number and that's it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length)

Comment: can't be done with scanf, but scanf can be used only for string(input without white space & new line chars)  not for text, usually setting terminal line length(mostly 80 chars) will cover all use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only you can know what length is sufficient for your needs.

If there is a limited set or range of valid inputs, you can use the length of the maximum valid input + 1.

If there isn't a limit to the maximum valid input, either you need to decide that your program doesn't support input longer than X and set that as the limit, or implement reading in a loop into a dynamically growing buffer (e.g., using `realloc` as needed).

And always remember to limit the maximum allowed input length when reading, so that it's not possible to overflow your buffer with excessive input. (Using `fgets` is often the simplest to get right.)