# Why does a 'segmentation fault' occur in this code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
void loop(char * a){
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%s\n", a);
  }
}

int main(){
  char str[] = "";

  printf("input:");
  scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

  loop(str);

  return 0;
}
```

There's nothing wrong when I input short string,
but the problem is that when I input longer string.

For example,

input:abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

abcdefghijkl

input:

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

abcdefghijklm

*exited, segmentation fault*

Why does this error occur?
Is this related to buffer overflow?

Comment: `str` is an array of size 0.

Comment: I think there is a typo, your loop function is not called..

Comment: @Damien It is size 1 (containing only terminating null-character)

Comment: Also worth to mention which are the root causes of segmentation fault.
It can help understanding which memory region triggers the fault.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: @MarcoFrau Thanks for the advice! I'll take care of that part next time.

Answer (score 2):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by writing to out-of-range to the 1-element array `str`, allowing anything to happen.

Allocate enough buffer and limit the maximum length to read to avoid buffer overflow.

```
int main(){
  char str[102400] = ""; /* allocate enough size */

  printf("input:");
  scanf("%102399[^\n]s", str); /* limit the length to read (the size of buffer minus one for terminating null-charater) */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Telling rookies to allocate 102400 bytes on the stack isn't great advise, however... You might want to edit that to a lower size.

Answer (score 2):

The way you define `str`:

```
char str[] = "";
```

It is exactly big enough to contain a zero-length string, i.e. it's an array of length 1.  So any larger string that you try to write to it will overrun the buffer, triggering  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should give your buffer a size that will be large enough to accept the size of string you'll expect.

```
char str[100];
```

And update the `scanf` call to limit the number of characters:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]s", str);
```

Comment: Ok I got it, but what if I'm not sure how large the input would be?

Comment: @L-IKEA [c - How can I read an input string of unknown length? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length)

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks a lot! I wonder if the rookie (like me) could come up with such complicated way.