# How to start from the smallest digit?

Tags: c

I was self studying on my Arithmetic and I encounter a problem. My goal is to find the least number not the greatest. I'm quite confused.

**Example output**

```
Enter n: 42123647
Smallest digit = 7
```

**Program**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num1, num2, num3=0;
    printf("Enter n: ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        while(num1>0){
            num2 = num1 % 10;
            if(num3<num2){
                num3=num2;
            }
            num1 = num1 * 10;
        }
        printf("Smallest digit = %d",num3);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: init num3 with 9 and invert if num3<num2 test...

Comment: 42123647 % 10 = 7 so it outputs correctly but it is not what you want.

Comment: Also if you try printing num1 in the loop you will notice it is not decreasing but it is increasing and then goes to negative values and stops the loop.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 10?  Multiplication is not the operation you want.

Comment: It might be helpful to use more descriptive variable names. It's easier, in my experience, to make algorithmic mistakes if you haven't clearly defined your terms (and thus variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems where `sizeof (int)` is 4, the statement

```
num1 = num1 * 10;
```

will quickly (within two iterations) cause *signed integer overflow* when the input is `42123647`, as `INT_MAX` is `2147483647`

The behaviour of this program is [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when this occurs.

---

After retrieving the *least significant digit* with `% 10`, try dividing your input by 10.

Additionally, you want to check that your current digit is *less than* your current minimum value, and initialize your minimum value to a value *greater than or equal* to the maximum possible value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input;
    int min = 10;

    printf("Enter n: ");

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &input)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (input > 0) {
        int digit = input % 10;

        if (digit < min)
            min = digit;

        input /= 10;
    }

    printf("Smallest digit = %d\n", min);
}
```

Comment: All good as long as you keep input in range of long int (as you mentioned). Otherwise you should move on a char array based solution.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you want to use division (instead of multiplication) to move to the next digit.

Also use a bottom-tested loop so that the case of just entering a zero as the number works correctly. A bottom-tested loop guarantees at least one pass through the loop.

The following code works as long as a proper number is entered. The %d format specifier, used with scanf, will essentially ignore a leading zero (i.e. if 0123 is entered then the smallest digit will be 1 instead of 0).

```
/* find a number's smallest digit

*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("enter n: ");
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    int smallestDigit = 9;
    do {
        int currentDigit = number % 10;
        if (currentDigit < smallestDigit) {
            smallestDigit = currentDigit;
        }
        number /= 10;                
    } while (number > 0);
    printf("\n");
    printf("smallest digit = %d\n", smallestDigit);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A char array (string) based solution in case your input is too large and overflows the variable as mentioned in other answers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isNumeric(char *str);

int main(void) {
    char *input;
    int min = 9;
    int digit;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    input = inputString(stdin,10); // explained later in answer
    if( isNumeric(input) == 0 ) {
        printf("Not a number.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for( int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        digit = input[i] - '0'; // ascii values
        if (digit < min)
            min = digit;
    }

    printf("Smallest digit = %d\n", min);
}

int isNumeric(char *str) {
    if( str[0] == '\0' )
        return 0;
    for( int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if( !isdigit(str[i]) ) 
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

#### Important

**inputString(stdin,10)** is a function call from a function implementation that exist in this stack overflow question [C-read-variable-length-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length).