# Read string with scanf() without knowing the length

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to read a string (str) from the user and a number (num) via scanf() but I don't know how to initialize str correctly.

```
int main(void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    int num;
    scanf("%s %d", str, &num);
    printf("str: %s\nnum: %d\n", str, num);
}
```

If I do it like this I get a segmentation fault.

My problem is that I don't know the length of str so I can't say something like this:

```
char str[20];
```

and I'm also not allowed to hardcode some high amount of index e.g.:

```
char str[999];
```

My question now: How can I initialize str in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate (among many): [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length) Quite possibly `scanf` with `%s` is the wrong tool for the job - it stops scanning a string at the first space. With `fgets()` you can tell from the absence of a newline in the buffer that the read was not completed. You can then reallocate the buffer and continue the read.

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea seems a bit overcomplicated but if thats the only possibility?

Comment: Reliable input is often non-trivial operation, especially when it is completely open-ended.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do know there are other ways for handling this but I don't know any other way that is reliable than this present solution. I advise you just keep the solution in a separate c file(modularize it).

Comment: You should probably disclose the constraints under which you are working — they are non-standard.  Specifying `char str[1024];` and using `%1023s` is a reasonable mechanism in most circumstances.  It is simpler than the alternatives.  You're only looking for a single word — meaning a sequence of characters that aren't white space characters — or you wouldn't be using `%s`.

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea unusal situations like this rarely have a one-function-fits-all solution.

Comment: To _read_ a string, use  from the user, use `"%*s"`.  This will read a "word" input of any length, but does not save it.  To read a line, use `"%*[^n]%*c"`.  To also save requires more work.

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations provide for a `%ms` specifier to allocate memory as required by the POSIX specification of [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).  Even some Unix-like systems (e.g. macOS Monterey 12.x and earlier) do not provide it.

If that is available (check the manual), this will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str = NULL;
    int num;
    scanf("%ms %d", &str, &num);
    printf("str: %s\nnum: %d\n", str, num);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

To capture a string that includes space and tab, but no digits,

```
scanf("%m[^\n0123456789] %d", &str, &num);
```

could be used

Comment: This worked only for a word. If you try a sentence it will print the first word before space(' ').

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea — that's not a legitimate critique: the question attempts to use `%s`, and this answer follows the question.  The question doesn't specify an alternative behaviour.  If the OP wanted to read a line, then [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX's [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) might be appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wasn't critiquing but just giving a heads up.